# List serialization to XML in Spring

Tags: xml, spring, api, serialization

I want to serialize in my controller List of Country objects to XML in Spring, but I receive data in incorrect format, like this:

```
<List>
   <item>
      <country><id>1</id><iso>AF</iso><namePl>Afganistan</namePl><citizenshipPl>Afganistanu</citizenshipPl><nameEn>AFGHANISTAN</nameEn><citizenshipEn>of Afghanistan</citizenshipEn></country>
   </item>
   <item>
      <country><id>2</id><iso>AL</iso><namePl>Albania</namePl><citizenshipPl>Albanii</citizenshipPl><nameEn>ALBANIA</nameEn><citizenshipEn>of Albania</citizenshipEn></country>
   </item>
</List>
```

and I want to get following format:

```
<countries>
   <country>
      <id>1</id><iso>AF</is>o<namePl>Afganistan</namePl><citizenshipPl>Afganistanu</citizenshipPl><nameEn>AFGHANISTAN</nameEn><citizenshipEn>of Afghanistan</citizenshipEn>
   </country>
   <country>
      <id>2</id><iso>AL</iso><namePl>Albania</namePl><citizenshipPl>Albanii</citizenshipPl><nameEn>ALBANIA</nameEn><citizenshipEn>of Albania</citizenshipEn>
   </country>
</countries>
```

do You know what am I doing wrong? How to set name of xml nodes as I want? Where I should put node names values?

My classes:

CountryVO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor

@XmlRootElement(name = "country")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "country")
public class CountryVO implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String iso;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String namePl;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String citizenshipPl;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String nameEn;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String citizenshipEn;
}
```

CountriesVO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor

public class CountriesVO implements Serializable {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "country")
    private List<CountryVO> countries;
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/country")
public class CountryWebService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceBundleService resourceBundleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/country", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String getCountries() throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        List<Country> countries = countryService.getAll();
        List<CountryVO> output = new ArrayList();
        String citizenshipEn,citizenshipPl, xmlString;

        for (Country country : countries) {
            citizenshipEn=resourceBundleService.getStringValue(ResourceBundleService.ResourceBundle.NATIONALITIES,ResourceBundleService.LANG_EN,country.getIso());
            citizenshipPl=resourceBundleService.getStringValue(ResourceBundleService.ResourceBundle.NATIONALITIES,ResourceBundleService.LANG_PL,country.getIso());
            output.add(new CountryVO(country.getId(),country.getIso(),country.getNamePl(),citizenshipPl,country.getName(),citizenshipEn));
        }

        return xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(output);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to annotate CountriesVO as JacksonXmlRootElement:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "countries")
public class CountriesVO implements Serializable {
    /** content skipped */
}
```

And use it as a wrapper during serialization:

```
xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new CountriesVO(output));
```

Update:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "countries")
public class CountriesVO implements Serializable {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "country")
    private List<CountryVO> countries;
}

public class CountryVO implements Serializable {

}
```

Creating and serializing beans:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
List<CountryVO> output = new ArrayList();
output.add(new CountryVO());
output.add(new CountryVO());
String str = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new CountriesVO(output));
System.out.println(str);
```

Produces:

```
<countries>
    <country>
        <id/>
        <iso/>
        <namePl/>
        <citizenshipPl/>
        <nameEn/>
        <citizenshipEn/>
    </country>
    <country>
        <id/>
        <iso/>
        <namePl/>
        <citizenshipPl/>
        <nameEn/>
        <citizenshipEn/>
    </country>
</countries>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but now i've got triple countries tag :) :  <countries>
    <countries>
        <countries>
            <id>1</id>
            <iso>AF</iso>
            <namePl>Afganistan</namePl>
            <citizenshipPl>Afganistanu</citizenshipPl>
            <nameEn>AFGHANISTAN</nameEn>
            <citizenshipEn>of Afghanistan</citizenshipEn>
        </countries>
   </countries>
</countries>

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Updated answer with new configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now i receive

```
<countries>
    <countries>
        <countries>
            <id>1</id>
            <iso>AF</iso>
            <namePl>Afganistan</namePl>
            <citizenshipPl>Afganistanu</citizenshipPl>
            <nameEn>AFGHANISTAN</nameEn>
            <citizenshipEn>of Afghanistan</citizenshipEn>
        </countries>
   </countries>
</countries>
```

from following classes:
controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/country")
public class CountryWebService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceBundleService resourceBundleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/country", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String getCountries() throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        List<Country> countries = countryService.getAll();
        List<CountryVO> output = new ArrayList();
        String citizenshipEn,citizenshipPl;

        for (Country country : countries) {
            citizenshipEn=resourceBundleService.getStringValue(ResourceBundleService.ResourceBundle.NATIONALITIES,ResourceBundleService.LANG_EN,country.getIso());
            citizenshipPl=resourceBundleService.getStringValue(ResourceBundleService.ResourceBundle.NATIONALITIES,ResourceBundleService.LANG_PL,country.getIso());
            output.add(new CountryVO(country.getId(),country.getIso(),country.getNamePl(),citizenshipPl,country.getName(),citizenshipEn));
        }

        return xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new CountriesVO(output));

    }
}
```

CountryVO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor

@XmlRootElement(name = "country")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "country")
public class CountryVO implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String iso;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String namePl;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String citizenshipPl;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String nameEn;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String citizenshipEn;
}
```

CountriesVO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "countries")
public class CountriesVO implements Serializable {


    private List<CountryVO> countries;
}
```

Do You know what's wrong now? Also i use xStream library, and it works for me, but I think how to use jackson xml library to achieve my goal